# Incremental Linear Programming

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

I'm trying to implement 1D linear programming, but I feel like I'm missing something to connect the dots. I want to compute the convex hull of a point set, so my constraints are the lines formed by line pairs. I'm trying to make an incremental algorithm which adds the points/lines one by one.

```
min  x_m*a + y_m*b
s.t. x_i*a + y_i*b + z_i >= 0

a', b' -> optimize with regards to 1...i

if ( x_i*a' + y_i*b' + z_i >= 0 )
    do nothing
else 
    x_i*a' + y_i*b' + z_i = 0
    b' = (-z_i - x_i*a')/y_i
    a' = ?
```

I think I may have screwed up in my notation, and that's what's confusing me, but how do I calculate a' and b'?

I've tried rephrasing my problem:

I found an online vector drawer, so I hope these pictures make sense.

[2D](http://www.bodurov.com/VectorVisualizer/?vectors=1/2/0/1/2/0v7/3/0/7/3/0v2/2/0/2/2/0v5/5/0/5/5/0v4/1/0/4/1/0v4/3/0/4/3/0v1/4/0/1/4/0v2/3/0/2/3/0v3/0/0/3/10/0v1/4/0/5/5/0)

[3D](http://www.bodurov.com/VectorVisualizer/?vectors=1/2/3/1/2/3v3/2/3/3/2/3v4/4/3/4/4/3v1/6/2/1/6/2v-1/4/-1/-1/4/-1v1/1/-1/1/1/-1v3/3/0/3/3/10v3/3/0/3/3/0v4/4/4/4/4/4v1/3/4/1/3/4v4/1/4/4/1/4v4/4/4/1/3/4v1/3/4/4/1/4v4/1/4/4/4/4v1/-2/3/1/-2/3v-1/-2/3/-1/-2/3v-1/2/2/-1/2/2) (This has a weird rotation)

In 2D, the vertical line is just defined as an x-coordinate x_m, as it's just an infinite line. I need to find the drawn line, and the way I do this, is that I start with a line defined by y=ax+b, with b=-infinity and a=0. I then add each point one by one in random order. For each point, I check if it's under this line, and if not, I found a new line by locking this point, and going through all other points, finding the point on the other side of x_m, giving me the largest a when I draw a line through the locked point and the newly checked point. Eventually, I will find a line, through two points, intersecting x_m, with all other points beneath it.

So
    max  ax_m+b
    s.t. y_1 <= ax_1+b
        y_2 <= ax_2+b
        y_i <= ax_i+b

I have this working fine.

In 3D, I want to find the face, defined by 3 points(or a plane z = ax + by + c), with all other points beneath it, using linear programming. Here, I start with a horizontal plane at -infinity, adding the points one by one, and checking if they're under my plane. If they're not, I try to maximize the previously posted LP. To do this, I need to be able to maximize a function of the form z = ax+by, instead of just y=ax+b. (I disregard c like I disregard b in 2D when I lock one point and max in 1D).

```
min  x_m*a + y_m*b
s.t. x_1*a + y_1*b + z_1 >= 0
s.t. x_2*a + y_2*b + z_2 >= 0
s.t. x_i*a + y_i*b + z_i >= 0

a', b' -> optimize with regards to p_1,...,p_i

if ( x_i*a' + y_i*b' + z_i >= 0 )
    do nothing
else 
    x_i*a' + y_i*b' + z_i = 0
    b' = (-z_i - x_i*a')/y_i
    a' = ?
```

Does this make sense now?

Basically, I think I just need some way to incrementally solve linear programs in the form z = ax + by.

Comment: This is an odd way to compute the convex hull. However if you google "linear programming convex hull" you will have some luck. There are much more efficient convex hull algorithms if you are interested.

Comment: You're probably right, but I need this both for comparison and for another 3D algorithm which uses this too.

Comment: Tried rephrasing my question to make more sense.